# How can I change MUI Data grid footer and width?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, datagrid

I have a problem. I am using mui data grid to create data tables. But my footer component is not align center. I can not figure out what is problem ?

```
     <Box
        position="fixed"
        style={{
          width: "80%",
          height: "55vh",
        }}
      >
        {/* Filters */}
        <Grid mb={3}>
          <Button
            aria-owns={anchorEl ? "simple-menu" : undefined}
            aria-haspopup="true"
            onClick={handleFilterClick}
            variant="contained"
            color="secondary"
          >
            Filter
          </Button>

          <Menu
            id="simple-menu"
            anchorEl={anchorEl}
            open={Boolean(anchorEl)}
            onClose={handleFilterClose}
          >
            <Grid sx={{ px: 5, pb: 3 }}>
              <EmployeeFilter
                employeeFilters={employeeFilters}
                setEmployeeFilters={setEmployeeFilters}
                filters={filters}
                setFilters={setFilters}
                handleEmployeeFilter={handleEmployeeFilter}
              />
            </Grid>
          </Menu>
        </Grid>

        {/* Employee Table */}
        <DataGrid
          rows={employeesData}
          columns={columns}
          slots={{ toolbar: GridToolbar }}
          disableColumnFilter
          autoPageSize
          initialState={{
            columns: {
              columnVisibilityModel: {
                mobile: false,
                email: false,
              },
            },
          }}
        />
        {loading ? <Loading /> : null}
      </Box>
```

That's my code. I have set value 80% as a width when I make it 100% it just expand width of my page. I just want to show data grid with scrolling.

[image]

I get this type of screen. But I dont want it also footer is not align center. How can I fix this problem ?